# Style is not applied to iframe after deployment to web server

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, iframe, web-deployment

I am using `id` selector to set style for `iframe`:

```
<div class="text-center">    
    <iframe src="@Url.Content("~/HTML/slideView.html")" id="iframeStyle" 
            marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 401px) {
    #iframeStyle {
        width: 700px;
        height: 400px;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;             
    }
    #idImg {
        width: 700px;
        height: 400px;        
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #iframeStyle {
        width: 360px;
        height: 190px;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: none;          
    }
    #idImg {
        width: 360px;
        height: 190px;        
    }
}
```

metadata:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>   
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

It works perfectly at localhost and `#iframeStyle` is always resized when width of the browser is more than `400px` or less `400px`.

However, after deploying to smarterasp.net, then `#iframeStyle` is **always** set to `@media screen and (max-width: 400px)` even I open the web site at wide display(at Personal Computer). That is, I always see is just small `iframe` and the size is not changed if I even resize the browser.

**How to set properly style for** `iframe`**?**

Comment: Hi, can you share you meta-data viewport ?
Usually what i do is have a default one without media-query to specify the largest size ... also try swaping what comes first...

Comment: It loosk correct, i would suggest to 
1) have a fall back to be before the media-query and see what it does.
2) Add !important tag and see if it works.
3) Check the dev-console and see which one is being used and if anything changes when you resize the window :)

Comment: please accept my answer?

Comment: @WickStargazer I'll try your suggestion in the evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loosk correct, i would suggest to

1. have a fall back to be before the media-query and see what it does.
2. Add !important tag and see if it works.
3. Check the dev-console and see which one is being used and if anything changes when you resize the window

   [image]

pls let me know which one worked for u :)

**Update:**

Cause you are loading styles through **Razor**:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

then the style is not applied to plain `html` page.

Just load CSS without Razor and style will be applied to your html page:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: How can I set fall back to be before the media-query?

Comment: if you set css without a media query it automatically falls back to the css when not in particular width size

Comment: Question about your the third advice: How can I know what style is currently used from dev-console when I resize window?